# TCPDF calculating cell height

Tags: height, tcpdf

i've tryed searching but didn't found anything good yet, so problem is that I have pdf document that is generated with different amount of data in cells. So now I met a problem that I need to somehow calculate data or cell height..  now I had code like this..

```
$pdf->writeHTMLCell('', '', $pdf->margin_l, $pdf->margin_top + 29, $html, 0, 0, 0, true, 'L', true);
$pdf->writeHTMLCell('', '', $pdf->margin_l, $pdf->margin_top + 120, $html, 0, 0, 0, true, 'L', true);
$pdf->writeHTMLCell('', '', $pdf->margin_l, $pdf->margin_top + 210, $html, 0, 0, 0, true, 'L', true);
```

I need to get automatically calculated height variable.. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

TCPDF has got [GetY()](http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/classTCPDF.html#ae3b6169ba729309f289a5ac9680dd799) method which will give you ordinate of the current position..

You may use it like this: `$pdf->GetY()` where `$pdf` is your *TCPDF* class object..